# Hadoop cluster with some nodes of low disk space~

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

i'm now holding a cluster with 12 nodes. Some of them, specifically 8 nodes, have enough disk space. But the other 4 only have little space to use.

However, the other 4 nodes have still high RAM and CPU configuration. So my intention is to utilize the resources. But now, when i ran a algorithm, SlopeOne, the map will output so many intermediate data and store them on the disk. Thus there are some errors, which I pasted under this description.

I wonder:

1. If a node find it can't store the data locally, will it try to store the data to other nodes with enough disk space?
2. If a single node failed to store the data locally, will it start the work once again?
3. If some nodes with enough disk space finish a map job first, will it continue to run the jobs which were distributed to the low disk space ones?
4. I know I can set a parameter, which can limit the local space usage, and if a node exceed that limitation, the jobtracker won't give more jobs to that node. But will this method just keeps the node staying there without working?
5. Any suggestions that I can utilize the resources as well as keep the errors away?

Appreciate any ideas.

```
java.io.IOException: Spill failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:860)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$OldOutputCollector.collect(MapTask.java:466)
    at slopeone.SlopeOneTrainer$SlopeOneTrainMapper.map(SlopeOneTrainer.java:71)
    at slopeone.SlopeOneTrainer$SlopeOneTrainMapper.map(SlopeOneTrainer.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local directory for taskTracker/jobcache/job_201104070658_0006/attempt_201104070658_0006_m_000000_0/output/spill897.out
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapOutputFile.getSpillFileForWrite(MapOutputFile.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.access$1800(MapTask.java:686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer$SpillThread.run(MapTask.java:1173)
```

Comment: I have a similar question (I think) -- we're finding that when we have machines with heterogenous disk configurations, HDFS seems to fill up machines with less storage at the same rate as others.  It seems like there should be some ability for HDFS to reflect on disk usage and adjust.  Rebalancing works, but it's only temporary.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reducing the number of replications, as answered in this question [HDFS Reduced Replication Factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799535/hdfs-reduced-replication-factor)
The default replication factor is 3

Comment: I don't see how this is an answer to the question.  To be sure, reducing the replication factor will reduce overall disk consumption, but the overall problem from OP is still present.  Am I misunderstanding how this solves the problem?